# Heat equation with heat source in form of delta function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

Consider the problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}u_t-u_{xx}=\delta_0,&0<x<1,\ t>0\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0,&t>0,\\ u(x,0)=0,& 0\leq x\leq 1.\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Using Fourier transform one finds out that $$\hat u(\xi,t)=\frac{1}{\xi}\left(1-e^{-\xi t}\right),$$
but how can I relate this to the solution of the original problem?

Comment: Just make a inverse fourier transform on it and then you will get the solution.

Comment: The domain for $x$ is $[0,1]$.  The Fourier Transform is not correct.